# React Native property 'ref' does not exist on type 'intrinsicattributes & flatlistprops<unknown>'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

This is my component:

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import {FlatList as RNFlatList, FlatListProps} from 'react-native';

// interface IFlatList<ItemT> extends FlatListProps<ItemT> {}

function FlatList<ItemT = any>(props: FlatListProps<ItemT>) {
  return (
    <RNFlatList
      {...props}
      nestedScrollEnabled
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      // Performance settings
      removeClippedSubviews={true} // Unmount components when outside of window
      initialNumToRender={20} // Reduce initial render amount
      maxToRenderPerBatch={20} // Reduce number in each render batch
      updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100} // Increase time between renders
      windowSize={10} // Reduce the window size
    />
  );
}

export default memo(FlatList);
```

when I call it:

```
<FlatList
    ref={flatListRef}
    // others props
/>
```

and it shows warning as title then I cannot use the `ref`.

I try to add

```
interface ClassAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
    ref?: LegacyRef<T> | undefined;
}
```

but I still can't find a solution to add it into props.

So where is the right way that I can customize my component and using all the default props of React Native's component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the practical use cases of a "Custom FlatList", because it doesn't affect the style at all. You already can style each item using `renderItem`, so there's no need for a "Custom FlatList".
But if you REALLY want to, you should understand `ref` in React itself first before writing any custom component, then get to know `useRef`, `useImperativeHandle`. You have to pass the `ref` to `FlatList` itself using `forwardRef`.

Here's an example:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  FlatListProps,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

interface CustomFlatListProps<T> extends FlatListProps<T> {}

export const CustomFlatList = forwardRef<FlatList, CustomFlatListProps<any>>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return <FlatList ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
);

interface ItemData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

const demoData: ItemData[] = [
  { id: '1', title: 'something 1' },
  { id: '2', title: 'something 2' },
  { id: '3', title: 'something 3' },
];

export function DemoUsingCustomFlatList() {
  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);

  function _renderItem({ item }: { item: ItemData }) {
    return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <CustomFlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={demoData}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => flatListRef.current?.scrollToEnd()}>
        <Text>Click to scroll to end</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```